# Virtual environment not available for selection in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I have a Python project with several dependencies on modules which are installed into a virtual environment in my working directory.

The python import statements are linted with this message:

> No name 'storage' in module 'azure'pylint(no-name-in-module)
>   Unable to import 'azure.storage.filedatalake._models'pylint(import-error)

I cannot select the virtual environment from the command palette **because it is not present**.

I tried navigating to the directory above the venv directory and executing `.\env\Scripts\activate` and then executing the file. However i expect a `print()` statement to return *"something"* to the Python terminal.

Comment: Have you installed the python extension for VSCode? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot find the interpreter you want in the lower left corner, then you can directly edit your workspace configuration file -settings.json, like the following

[image]

In fact, probably because your workspace path is not a standard path defined by the system and VSCode cannot detect your interpreter. If some of your virtual environments are in the same folder, you can use the following settings to let VSCode know where to find your interpreter

[image]

Comment: I added the path to the python.exe where the virtual environment is installed and the default Python interpreter changed (bottom left of VSC). I cannot however find Python: Venv Path setting demonstrated in the second screenshot.